# Who are the two men credited with inventing logarithms?

Tags: logarithms, math-history

This is a bonus question on a pre-calculus quiz I've been tasked with grading. Napier is clearly one of the answers. Who should I accept for the second inventor? In particular, should Newton be considered correct?

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#History), the other inventor is [Joost Bürgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jost_B%C3%BCrgi), who discovered the logarithms earlier but published after Napier.

Comment: I would think Napier and Henry Briggs would be the two most likely candidates.

Comment: Maybe Burgi, but he don't get no respect.

Comment: I might be wrong, but ... Messrs. Baseten and Natural?

Comment: I would not give credit for Newton. I would give credit for Napier and Briggs or (in the unlikely event that anyone comes up with it) Napier and Bürgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bürgi did invent the logarithms, but since he did not publish anything about them I doubt he should be credited. Henry Briggs, on the other side, convinced Napier that logarithms in base 10 would have been more useful that the ones Napier devised, and after having his benediction started compiling the decimal tables. Therefore I would stick with Briggs.

Newton perused logarithms, but he could not be considered their inventor.

Comment: Bürgi did publish, in $1620$, possibly as much as $32$ years after he did the actual work.